# What is the maximum seed value N for mysql RAND(N)

Tags: mysql

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

`...RAND(N)...If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed value,...`

what is the maximum possible value of N?

By saying "integer" they mean the *mysql **type** integer* (signed -2147483648, 2147483647 / unsigned 0, 4294967295 ) or something else?

Comment: @Strawberry do you have any sources on that?

Comment: This _definitely_ works with values larger than `2^32`, I've just tested it. But what I've noticed is a weird pattern. The values for `RAND(2147483647)`, `RAND(2147483647 * 2 + 1)`, `RAND(2147483647 * 3 + 2)` and so on are _almost_ the same, about 8 decimal digits.

Comment: guys your opinions on this link user3414693 posted? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69999

Comment: Actually, it appears to be BIGINT max, i.e. 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By saying "integer" they mean the mysql type integer?

It would be the maximum value for [BIG INTEGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) as 18446744073709551615

Check this [MYSQL BUG](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69999)

Comment: Your value is correct. Your statement in support of it is confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think because you've capitalized the word 'INTEGER' it implies that you're referring to the specific data type rather than the grneral body of integer data types

Comment: @user3414693 remove the "Yes, i think" cause it contradicts with the rest of statement.

Comment: tested on `5.5.36-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` it appears maximum is 18446744073709551615, with numbers bigger than that, the results are the same